# How can I generate a new wallet based off of a seed phrase

Tags: solana-program, account, wallet, keypair, seed

I see wallets like phantom and solflare pop up with a list of accounts when you import a seed phrase. How does that work? How can you find all of those through code? Can you generate new ones? Also if I just generated a new keypair. How could I use that seed as the base for the rest of the wallets I make?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to hierarchical derivation, which essentially defines many different ways of generating a private key from a seed phrase.

For example, given a seed phrase like `immense soup feed arrest erupt arrow little nephew regular trap radio danger`, which `solana-keygen` gives a pubkey of `jtFuWc4r1Y6UNuU13LngguXuyozapVnRVfnv9VwqWKr`, you can do:

```
solana-keygen pubkey prompt://?key=0/1
<Paste the words here>
EqqwJANhbtzB2bwFv7N4wEQA8fj3hxAJsoq7iE9szEN8
```

Or

```
solana-keygen pubkey prompt://?full-path=m/44/2017/0/1
<Paste the words here>
97oZZGsDN5nobMDsk4XDhPHjExxqAS5ehfFRUAyBNHEF
```

Depending on your derivation path, you'll different private keys.

More information in the Solana docs at https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/paper-wallet#hierarchical-derivation

To do this in code, you can use the `ed25519_dalek_bip32` crate, and do something like:

```
let seed = "blouse clerk fault regular grocery chat figure squeeze question catalog athlete predict";
let derivation_path = "44'/501'";
let extended = ed25519_dalek_bip32::ExtendedSecretKey::from_seed(seed)
        .and_then(|extended| extended.derive(&derivation_path))?;
let extended_public_key = extended.public_key();
ed25519_dalek::Keypair {
    secret: extended.secret_key,
    public: extended_public_key,
}
```

You can find the whole source code for `solana-keygen` at You can see all of the `solana-keygen` code at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/keygen/src/keygen.rs

Comment: How can I do this from code? And not CLI

Comment: Updated with a code example

Comment: Do you have code for python I can use?